# no implicit conversion of String into Integer base62 encode rails

Tags: ruby, uuid, base62

```
uuid = Digest::SHA256.digest(SecureRandom.uuid)
id = Base62.encode(uuid)
```

no implicit conversion of String into Integer

line =  `id = Base62.encode(uuid)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]"  and "[mcve]" along with their linked pages. Your question isn't clear.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: thanks for asking, People care more as it should be written here, More than the question!! i want pass the uuid to base62 but, already solved Thankns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for pass string to base62

```
uuid = SecureRandom.uuid.gsub("-", "").hex
@id = uuid.base62_encode
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your code is going to work. Here's why:

`Base62.encode(num)` takes a base10 number and converts it into a base62 string. That's a problem for you as:

```
Digest::SHA256.digest(SecureRandom.uuid)
# => "\e\x1F\xD6yby\x02o\f)\xA2\x91\xD4\xFB\x85jd\xE0\xF7\xECtd\x8E\xA6\x9Ez\x99\xD8>\x04\nT"
```

Returns a string.

If you look at the code in the `base62-rb` gem, and the comment above the method, you can see it's comparing a string to an integer, which is the error I get when I try to replicate this:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed
```

Here's is the method from the gem:

```
# From base62-rb.rb line 8-20:

  # Encodes base10 (decimal) number to base62 string.
  def self.encode(num)
    return "0" if num == 0
    return nil if num < 0

    str = ""
    while num > 0
      # prepend base62 charaters
      str = KEYS[num % BASE] + str
      num = num / BASE
    end
    str
  end
```

All of this is of course predicated on the fact that you are using the `base62-rb` gem. So, perhaps you can give us some context and let us know what you've tried?

Comment: You're mixing comments and an answer. If you're unsure of the question then the best course is to vote the question down and vote to close it, then explain in a comment why the question has problems. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing explain this.